# How to delete files in a location except executable files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have created a batch script to delete 7 days older files as follows:

```
ForFiles /p "C:\Users\John.Kapen\Desktop" /s /d -7 /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

But this is deleting executable files and folders as well.
I tried below command to exclude executable file deletion. But not working:

```
for /f %%F in ('C:\Users\John.Kapen\Desktop /b /d -7 /a-d ^| findstr /vile ".exe"') do del "%%F"
```

Could someone help me here?

Comment: You need to tell the command to exclude them. An in doing so, I recommend using the syntax available form the command help information, (`forfiles /?`). Something along the lines of this seems reasonable: `ForFiles /P "C:\Users\John.Kapen\Desktop" /S /D -7 /C "Cmd /C If @IsDir==FALSE If /I Not @Ext==0x22exe0x22 Del @File"`

Comment: You're missing `dir` in the second approach; it should actually read: `for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir "%UserProfile%\Desktop" /B /A:-D ^| findstr /VILE ".exe"') do del "%%F"`; and note that there is no `/D -7` option for `dir`!

Comment: In my previous comment, I probably didn't need to include the `If ISDir==FALSE` part, because obviously `Del` doesn't remove directories. That means, upon completion of the command, you'll probably want to remove any, now empty, directories. You could probably do that similarly: `ForFiles /P "C:\Users\John.Kapen\Desktop" /S /C "Cmd /C If
 @IsDir==TRUE RD @File 20x3ENUL" 2>NUL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `forfiles /?` "manpage" contains following information:

```
...
                    @ext     - returns only the extension of the
                               file.
...
Examples:
...
  FORFILES /M *.txt /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE notepad.exe @file"
```

You can try something like (not tested):

```
ForFiles /p "C:\Users\John.Kapen\Desktop" /s /d -7 /c "cmd /c if NOT @ext=="""exe""" del @file"
```

Comment: You cannot escape `"` by doubling them, you need to use either `\"` or `0x22`, the latter of which is preferable since it does not interfere with the parser `cmd.exe`, but the former does due to the `"` (note that the `\"` escaping and also the hex code `0x22` are just features of `forfiles`, the parser does not know any of these things)...

Comment: Can I modify the same script to delete files from all drives except C drive?So that I can place the script anywhere, but will check and remove the files from all the drives available in the system, except C drive.
@echo off
set YYYY=%date:~10,4%
set MM=%date:~7,2%
set DD=%date:~4,2%
set filename=%DD%%MM%%YYYY%
set dir=C:\Users\John.Kapen\Desktop


ForFiles /p "%dir%" /s /d -3 /c "cmd /c if NOT @ext=="""exe""" if NOT @ext=="""EXE""" del @file"